# GameMaker for iPhone development

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, game-maker

How does GameMaker compare to XCode/Objective-C for iPhone development?
I have an idea of GameMaker being really easy to use, but rather restricted in its functionality, while XCode/Objective-C is a lot harder to use but of course as flexible as can be (by design).
I am thinking about picking up a book on one of the two (GameMaker or XCode/Objective-C), as I would like to develop iPhone apps, but am finding it hard to figure out the pros and cons.
Any input will be appreciated :) :)

Comment: :) I see u have 'NS' as part of your nick. I'm thinking that you may not be entirely objective?Can you maybe give some arguments for using Obj-C over GameMaker

Comment: Ha! I'm sorry but no I can't. I've tried using programs like Gamesalad and Stencyl in the past and I've never been any good with them. I don't know enough to tell you why coding directly would be better or worse, just that code is my personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can develop almost everything with Game Maker, but why you shouldn't is because it has **really bad performance**. I have read lot of reviews telling about games done with GM that are completely draining the battery. I won't choose this option.

I would rather look for something like **Unity3D** who's badass, or something cheaper like **Corona SDK**. The best way is still by using the native tools like xCode for iOS, and Eclipse Java for Android. But that's a choice that depends of the amount of time you want to spend for the development.

Update: The way to go is [**cocos2d-x**](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/).

Comment: Just a clarification here -- GameMaker does **not** have bad performance so long as you are compiling with Yoyocompiler (YYC), rather than just running the interpreted build.  It **does** drain your battery.  The reason for this is that it is running a game loop 30 or 60 times per second, as it is a game engine.

Unity is much more easier to deal with for anything with 3D, but has a steeper learning curve and takes more work to produce something 2D.  It also is a game engine and generally redraws the whole screen every frame, so it also burns your battery.